# Truncate 2d arrays of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JavaScript and I wanted to truncate numbers (23.123) to 23.

```
arr = [
[1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123],
[1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123], 
[1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123]
]
```

I tried Math.trunc and even with lodash (_.toInteger) but was not getting results. I may have screwed in logic.

I need output like this.

```
output = [
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[1, 2, 3, 4],
[1, 2, 3, 4],
]
```

I just wanna know how can we achieve this.

Comment: *"I may have screwed in logic.*" We can't fix a problem we can't see. Please [edit] the question and add the code you've tried with `Math.trunc` and `_.toInteger`.

Comment: `Math.round` ??

Comment: Use High Order Functions to iterate through array first. then use same Math.truc() function to truncate element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```js
const arr = [
  [1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123],
  [1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123], 
  [1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123]
]

const nestedArr = arr.map(nestedArr => nestedArr.map(item => item.toFixed(0)))
console.log(nestedArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you.

```js
const arr = [
  [1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123],
  [1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123],
  [1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123]
]

const allEls = arr.map((el) => {
  return el.map((num) => Math.trunc(num))
})

console.log(allEls)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use Math.trunc function

```
let arr = [
[1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123],
[1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123], 
[1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123]
];    
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
        arr[i][j] = Math.trunc(arr[i][j]);
    }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the method parseInt ?

```js
var arr = [
[1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123],
[1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123], 
[1.05, 2.0123, 3.123, 4.123]
];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    var newArray = arr[i];
  
  for(var bis = 0; bis < newArray.length; bis++)
  {
    console.log(parseInt(newArray[bis]));
  }
}
```

See the doc : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Hope this helps you.